# Is there any Windows mobile application for Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I want to install Dynamics CRM 2011 on my **windows 7 mobile phone** So that I should be in sync with the Leads/Contact details etc added by my co-workers. Is there any Windows ***Mobile application which allows me to Add record and so would be reflected on the Web to other employees as well?***

I have tried a few applications downloaded from MarketPlace but none of them could keep the synchronization with complete database *(i.e. I am not able to see the record added by another user and vice-versa)*

Please suggest such application.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with Resco. But the app needs to be customized, and still you have all the limitations of you account.

Comment: Thanks @Draiden. But Resco doesn't solve my purpose. When I installed this application on my phone It doesn't synchronize the application at all. When I try to synchronize the application it shows message stating "The request contains no response"

Comment: It's very weird, I installed it on my win phone 7 and i was able to use the crm. Use the browser on the phone is not an option? (i know that you will not have local db :S)

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with my application. In fact I have tried with 2 different devices also. Did you make any changes from Web to allow synchronization with Mobile application?

Comment: Nothing particular, are you using on premise or online? The online one can be dodgy (since now is probably 2013), and the on premise require that you are able to resolve the address from the mobile device, so is possible that you need to try if you are able to access the crm using the web interface.

Comment: Yah.. I agree with your point. I am using Online and yet in 2011.

Comment: could you please send an e-mail to mobilecrm@resco.net? I am sure our support team will help you resolve the issue and you'll have a working Mobile CRM in no time. My apologies for the delayed response - I accidentally stumbled on this questions only now. Zuzana from Resco